# Accessing array of structure using pointer. ( Something wrong with the code)

Tags: c, pointers, structure

There is an array of structure, which is passed to accept function so as to store some value in the structure. The loop inside the accept function iterates only single time, only upto scanf.

```
struct emp
{
    int age;
    char name[20];
    float sal;
};

void display(struct emp *);
void accept(struct emp *);

void main()
{
clrscr();
struct emp E[3];
accept(E);
display(E);
getch();
}

void accept(struct emp *p)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  printf("Enter age, name and sal: ");
  scanf("%d %s %f",&(p+i)->age,(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->sal);
}
}

void display(struct emp *p)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
printf("Result: %d %s %f",(p+i)->age,(p+i)->name,(p+i)->sal);
}
}
```

Please rectify the code.

Comment: and what happens then? does the program crash, does it hang, is the display function called, ...?

Comment: information that is still missing: what are you trying to input, what happens when you break in the function using your debugger, ...

Comment: show one of your input

Comment: After fixing the signature of `main` and removing `clrscr` and `getch` which are platform-specific, it [appears to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f02894431404dbf7) (newlines added after testing for readability).

Comment: Signature of main () ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are taking input `name` with space characters, try this way:

```
scanf("%d %[^\n]s %f",&(p+i)->age,(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->sal);
```

**N.B:** I also removed `clrscr()` and `getch()` and used `int main()` instead of `void main()`. Because these were giving errors.

Comment: Nice :-) .Please explain what u have done, it works well. Thanks

Comment: `%[^\n]s` includes the space characters.

Comment: I am not taking any names with space characters, just 1 word names. Still... its crashing

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
scanf("%d %s %f\n",&(p+i)->age,(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->sal);
```

Comment: After you enters the float value, an input will be required to break the scanf so \n would act as that input. It will break the control on enter key.

Answer (score -1):

Try reading user input using the gets() function instead (reads a whole line), then use sscanf() to read the data into the variables.

Comment: "The [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard. `fgets()` and `gets_s()` are the recommended replacements."

Comment: Well Quentin, given the apparently novice level of the poster (no offense), being able to read the data is the goal here, not writing professional applications. The point is to simply read a line of data and process them, which the OP seems not able to do now, so I just recommended using the most basic form of "input" function (and the easiest too). Using a more "safe" form of the function is another matter, and of little interest to the OP at this point. And downvoting just for this is counterproductive and discouraging. Should I better not post an answer?

Comment: I understand what you mean. But trying to avoid explaining `fgets` by recommending `gets` is excessive : OP *can* take twelve additionnal seconds to understand what `fgets`'s size parameter trivially does, rather than learning to use a defunct function that is broken by design and have to unlearn it later. If you insist on recommending `gets`, at least you should mention that it is but a temporary "facilitation".

Comment: Apart form `gets` (which is in its own special case of alarming, unfixable deprecation), you are not explaining what's wrong with OP's code, and why an intermediate buffer would help. This would be very valuable information and improve your answer quite a bit over the "your thing is broken, use that stuff instead" bar.

Comment: I did explain actually, gets() or (gets_s()) reads a whole line of input text (until end-of-line [Enter] is reached) but obviously you didn't see it, as you focused on gets() instead.

Comment: I'm actually trying to be constructive, I'm not having a go at you. I genuinely don't understant how an intermediate buffer would help, whether it be filled with `gets` or something else ; especially since OP's code with `scanf` [actually works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f02894431404dbf7) (with minor fixes to make it compile at all).

Comment: The gets()/gets_s() function is the recommended one for console input. It reads a LINE of text (and yes, will not return before [Enter] is pressed). Then the author can use sscanf() to read the data to variables, and validate the input (eg check how many variables were read and assigned). scanf() is more unpredictable, will wait until all variables are read - in the same or another line -, treats spaces and newlines the same, and fails miserably if user input is anything but "perfect". Will only return prematurely (read less variables than those asked) if an end-of-file (Ctrl-Z) is in input .

Comment: Now that's answer fuel ;)